# If-statement with changing url

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

What is wrong with this function? The first if-statement does work. But the else-statement doesn't work.

```
function func() {
    if (document.getElementById("pic2").src = "pause.png") {
        document.getElementById("pic2").src = "play.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pic2").src == "pause.png";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="all" onclick="func()" onmouseover="func3()">
            <div id="background" onclick="func()" onmouseout="func2()"></div>
            <div id="pic">
                <img id="pic2" src="pause.png">
            </div>
            <video>
                <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: is that a typo error? you have used assignment operator in if statement

Comment: do you need to toggle images on click ?

Comment: Yes! How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few things which didn't let you toggle your img src.

1. Improper condition check. `if (document.getElementById("pic2").src = "pause.png")` must be `if (document.getElementById("pic2").src`**==**`"pause.png")`
2. `document.getElementById("pic2").src` would give you the full path to your image. Its better to trim it down to the image name (with extension) using `img_url.substr(img_url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);`

```js
function func() {
    var img_url = document.getElementById("pic2").src;
    var img = img_url.substr(img_url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    if (img  == "pause.png") {
        document.getElementById("pic2").src = "play.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pic2").src = "pause.png";
    }
}

function func2(){
 // your func2
}

function func3(){
 // your func3
}
```

```html
<div id="all" onclick="func()" onmouseover="func3()">
            <div id="background" onclick="func()" onmouseout="func2()"></div>
            <div id="pic">
                <img id="pic2" src="pause.png">
            </div>
            <video>
                <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to achieve that every time you click on #all, the image source has to change.

Comment: @Soccerlife how is that possible, i have added the code with output now, just check and confirm

Answer (score 0):

single equal signs sign is for assign a value. you have to add two equals to compare two variables or values.
 like this:-

```
function func() {
    if (document.getElementById("pic2").src == "pause.png") {
        document.getElementById("pic2").src = "play.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pic2").src = "pause.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
    function func() {

        var image = document.getElementById("pic2");// more efficient way

        if (image.src  == "pause.png") { // double equal sign here

            image.src = "play.png"; // equal sign here
        } else {
            image.src = "pause.png";// equal sign here
        }
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, You come here, It's very kind of you